Gnome Kiosk Mode
I have deployed a kiosk mode system with gnome-kiosk on Ubuntu 24.
Kiosk mode in gnome limits user interaction for a self-service computer.
The session is automatically started via GDM, and when the key combination CTRL is pressed, the system will switch to a tty allowing connection with the current user.
Do you have any idea how to block this behaviour and prevent the user from obtaining a tty with this key combination?
Thank you,

This question is similar to: How to get fewer ttys with Systemd?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

(answer of this post used as a basis)
Perhaps try the following;
sudo tee -a /etc/init/tty3.override <<<"manual"

If there are other TTYs with such issue, change the 3 to the TTYs number or just follow the solution I've linked above

I don't know why OP accepted this, but /etc/init hasn't been used since Ubuntu 15.04 when it switched to systemd as the default.
